# Why round trip to introspection point on each call?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am seeing for each protected API call, a call to the introspection endpoint of identity server. Can I stop this from happening?

We have a React application that uses implicit flow. When the application receives the access token it is then used to make calls to another Web API with the access token. What we noticed is the introspection endpoint is called on each call.

I thought JWT tokens do not need to be validated against the issuer each time a call is made.

I have the following app setup:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = identityServiceUri;
                    options.ApiName = "SMAppServices";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                });
```

Comment: They don't unless you set up introspection. By default it's not enabled.

Comment: Where would you set this up? Are you saying we disable it in identity server? If so what if other applications require introspection?

Comment: So the introspection is used by default only if the token type is not a JWT but a reference token instead. So if you are using JWT's, you should not get introspection behaviour at all, but your question now does not have any set up showcased so it won't be possible to help any further. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html

Comment: The link you provided uses AddJwtBearer() instead of AddIdentityServerAuthentication(). Is this the issue and if so why?

Comment: Its not the issue. Firstly you need to understand what type of client your react app is and whether it is configured to use ref tokens. All that is within the identity provider config.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably set the access token type to reference type. You can check this in the client configuration in the IdentityServer. There is a property called AccessTokenType in the Client class.